# Transition animation from one view controller to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I have 2 view controller with navigation controller. I'm pushing one firstViewController to secondViewController. i'm currently using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
```

but the transition is secondView come in from the right. What i'm trying to do is secondView come in from the back and firstView fading out while secondView fading in.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: you can achieve reverse second vc fade in and first vc fade out

Comment: Do you have some example that can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Push/Pop UIVIewController FadeIn/FadeOut in Swift

```
class FadeInPushSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    var animated: Bool = true

    override func perform() {

        if var sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController, var destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {

            var transition: CATransition = CATransition()

            transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade
            sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
            sourceViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)


        }
    }

}

class FadeOutPopSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {

        if var sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController as? UIViewController, var destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController as? UIViewController {

            var transition: CATransition = CATransition()

            transition.duration = 0.4
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
            transition.type = kCATransitionFade; //kCATransitionMoveIn; //, kCATransitionPush, kCATransitionReveal, kCATransitionFade

            sourceViewController.view.window?.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: "kCATransition")
            sourceViewController.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)
        }
    }

}
```